# Unordered list alignment and page-break issues

Tags: html, css, erb

The output is a result of saving/printing as pdf, based on an erb template. The content is dynamicly rendered but maybe I can explain myself with a [static example](https://plnkr.co/edit/RwwbuGGQEKtxBuvw).

I have been running around in circles, playing with `block`, `page-break`, `list-style-position`, without full results.

**I'm having trouble making the numbering inline with the title (h2), while making sure that neither the title is split among pages, nor the 1st paragraph is split from the title. I also need for the second line of the title to be aligned right below the numbering.** Every time I solve one thing, I mess another one.

I've changed `inline`, to `block`, because I read that that might the reason why the `page-break` was being "ignored", but things still get split.

On my static example, since the paragraphs are listed one by one, I guess that to make sure that the title wouldn't be split from the 1st paragraph, I could add a wrapping div. That's not an ideal solution for me, because on my real code, I have something like this (below), which renders all paragraphs.

```
 <% point_content.call(key.to_s.delete_suffix('_title'), price_list_variant).each do |paragraph| %>
  <p><%= paragraph %></p>
 <% end %>
```

Anyway, I tried adding a div there and then the alignments are ruined and also the numbering (everything becomes 0).

Maybe someone has a better idea for this, and understands why this is not working as expected.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: none of the styles apply: `<div="price_list">` should be `<div id="price_list">`

Comment: @Alex thank you. Indeed on my example I should have added id. Corrected it already. Locally I had it correctly. Nevertheless, that doesn't solve my issues, unfortunately. Because I can't get the inline numbering + h2, while not spliting h2 between pages and having the h2 2nd line aligned right below the numbering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
function withPageBreak() {
  const titles = document.querySelectorAll("h2");
  titles.forEach(el => el.classList.add("with-page-break"));
  window.print();
  titles.forEach(el => el.classList.remove("with-page-break"));
}
```

```css
h2 {
  display: list-item;
  list-style: inside;
  list-style-type: decimal;
}

.with-page-break {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-after: avoid;
}

h2::marker {
  color: red;
}

li {
  display: block;
}

@page {
  size: 8.5in 5in;
  margin: 1in;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="window.print()">Print without breaks</button>
<button onclick="withPageBreak()">Print with page breaks</button>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2>TITLETITLE TITLETITLE TITLETITLE TITLE TITLE TITLETITLE</h2>
    <p>Paragraph1</p>
    <p>Paragraph1</p>
    <p>Paragraph1</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>TITLETITLE TITLETITLE TITLETITLE TITLE TITLE TITLETITLE</h2>
    <p>Paragraph1</p>
    <p>Paragraph1</p>
    <p>Paragraph1</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```